# <button> element fails to acknowledge align-items CSS declaration (from flexbox)

Tags: html, css, firefox, flexbox

Styling form elements is a well-known pain.

I would like to have the text of a given `<button>` display in the bottom-right hand corner of that button.

Using **flexbox** with a `<div>` this as straightforward as:

```
div {
display: flex;
justify-content: flex-end;
align-items: flex-end;
}
```

But with the `<button>` it is rather less straightforward.

The really peculiar thing is that the `<button>` does acknowledge `justify-content: flex-end;` but not `align-items: flex-end;`.

**Example of *align-items* failing to override native styles of `<button>`:**

```css
div {
background-color: rgb(191, 191, 191);
}

div, button {
display: flex;
float: left;
width: 130px;
height: 100px;
margin-right: 12px;

justify-content: flex-end;
align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div>Div (flex)</div>
<button>Button (flex)</button>
```

Is there any way I can get `align-items: flex-end;` to work with the button, or is there any alternative way to have the text of a given `<button>` display in the bottom-left hand corner of that button?

---

**Browser:** I am using *Firefox 57.0.4*

Comment: Buttons can be block-level just fine. Wherever you're reading that from is making it up. I should point out that you're floating all the divs and buttons so the inline-level declarations become moot anyway.

Comment: *"The really peculiar thing is that the `<button>` does acknowledge `justify-content: left;` but not `align-items: flex-end;`."* ... `justify-content: flex-start` (same as `left` in LTR) is the default value. The default value of `align-items` is `flex-start`, not `flex-end`. So it makes sense.

Comment: Yeah, I mean floating is taking away the inline layout - showing how flex behavior is identical across blocks and inlines isn't as effective when you're not allowing the inlines to be inline ;)

Comment: When you're dealing with `justify-content` and values such as `left` and `right`, you've gone beyond flexbox. These values are defined in a different spec (CSS Box Alignment) and are intended to apply to all box models, not just flexbox (which has the proprietary `flex-start` and `flex-end`)

Comment: damn, was about to answer and they closed the question... this is actually a really good topic. From what I could experience, button doesn't accept a `align-items` declaration, but for most cases you can fake it by switching the axis and justify-content. In this particular case, `flex-direction:column; justify-content:flex-end` does the trick.

Comment: The reason `justify-content` works in block layout with `left` and `right`, and `align-items` doesn't, could be an implementation issue. This is all very new.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Michael - I updated the question from (default) `justify-content: left;` to non-default `justify-content: flex-end` to really hone in on the issue that one declaration is working while the other is not.

Comment: You're welcome. If your question is not about why `button` content doesn't respect flex properties, you should vote to re-open.

Comment: No, we're good - I'm satisfied that, in this instance, I'll need to use another element instead of `<button>`. On reflection, given that the element is a top-level form element which, when clicked, opens up a Level 2 sub-section of the form... `<h2>` is probably a good candidate. Thanks all three of you for your help.

Comment: @Rounin it's unlikely that the question will be re-opened... but please check the answer I provided above and let us know if it works for you. Bottom-left should be `flex-direction:column; justify-content:flex-end`, top-left:   `justify-content: flex-start; flex-direction:column;`

Comment: guys check the pen I just made... https://codepen.io/facundocorradini/pen/RxQMep I was able to position the content  in the four different corners by just changing the `flex-direction` and `align-items`, which for whatever reason works when there's no `justify-content` declared

Comment: Thank you @FacundoCorradini - yes I tried it. (When I saw it in your comment above I thought that it had the potential to be a nifty hack.) But it doesn't seem to work on `<button>` unfortunately. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Check your codepen in Firefox, @FacundoCorradini.

Comment: @Rounin I was at it right now, experimenting and reporting as I go... It looks awful in firefox, works perfectly in Chrome... and believe it or not, it works perfectly in IE. Think I'm having the weirdest dream.